# Tablet OLED with HDMI-INPUT?

Tags: hdmi, tablet

Is there any?
Quite hard to search on google and shopping sites IMO.

I need this tablet to have an OLED screen for maximum contrast quality.

It needs to have an HDMI-IN connection, so I can plug my desktop video output on it and use it temporarily as a monitor.

The price also matters as I'm ok with 1080p and  tablet size screen (even refurbished could work).

Obs.: it could be a notebook with the same requirements, just that i prefer a tablet.

Comment: The [**New XPS 15 7590**](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/new-xps-15-7590/spd/xps-15-7590-laptop) notebook from Dell has an OLED display, but it does not have an HDMI input connection. There aren't many tablets or notebooks with an HDMI input and combined with the OLED requirement, you're gonna end up with a very short list of options.

Comment: If you need the contrast for reading documents, an eInk monitor could also be an option, for example the [Onyx Boox MAX 2](https://onyxboox.com/boox_max2) ebook reader which can also function as an [HDMI monitor](https://youtu.be/SSv0g-pYMAk?t=601).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu is onyx fast, like in I could use it for games too? Doesnt need to be perfect, just as fast as a common monitor.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you just gave me an idea, may be that dell notebook could accept a plunplay card that works as a HDMI-IN?

Comment: As you can see from the linked video Onyx is quite slow. eInk is slow.

Comment: You could run a VNC server on the main computer and connect to it with a VNC client from the notebook to see the same image on both computers. Team Viewer might also work. If you are running Windows, Remote Desktop could also be an option. If you have Linux, X works over the network although not very good with modern applications (read OpenGL, 3D acceleration etc); Wayland is work in progress. Search for a screen mirroing/casting application, something like Miracast, Chrome Cast, https://superuser.com/q/668292/2357 etc.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Ive tried nomachine, the problem is the slow usb connection (compared to hdmi i guess). Often it lags and drops visual quality to big squares, using it with a oled smartphone

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be an OLED? My immediate thought is an iPad with Sidecar or Duet Display, but unfortunately they're not OLED. You could also do one of the various OLED equipped Galaxy Tabs with AirDisplay or iDisplay. While you could get a laptop, anything with an OLED panel is going to be super duper expensive. Also, can you elaborate on what software you need to run on the tablet/laptop? The use cases aren't usually the same. (cont.)

Comment: I'd also take a look at the [Asus ProArt PQ22UC](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/ProArt-PQ22UC/), a portable OLED monitor. It's got  Type-C and HDMI inputs.

Comment: @JMY1000 sounds good, will take a look, thx!

Comment: @JMY1000 that would be the answer if not for the $4000 price. Im ok with 1080p smaller (tablet size) screen, even refurbished could work. I need to update/improve my question, thx!

Comment: I still don't understand: when this tablet/laptop isn't connected to your desktop, what software are you trying to run on it?

Comment: @JMY1000 nothing special, just enough to let HDMI-IN work. Thats the point. I want it to be a xtreme contrast (OLED) cheap and fast (HDMI-IN) monitor. Nowadays we only have such with absurd prices (a single smart tv or 4k monitor costs more than my whole desktop, and that is absurd). So I only need 1080p, cheap alternative and why there is none? Why??? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99074/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-veganeye).

Comment: @JMY1000 Cool thx, but right now I need to sleep, :(